# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++ when trying to statically link

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, g++, centos7

I am trying to compile a simple program statically. I keep getting the following error:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -static
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lm
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
```

I removed pieces of code until I got down to the complete barebones:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    return 0;
}
```

Googling and looking on here haven't proven fruitful. How can I fix this problem?

Update: when I enable devtoolset-9, the error rearing stdc++ goes away but the other two remain. How can I fix?